# Macbook Pro not playing any chrome sounds, youtube videos not working, system audio is working

Tags: macbook-pro, bug

On my MacbookPro, no sites can play audio on either chrome or safari, and youtube and vimeo do not load.  However, I can still play my itunes music with or without headphones, so I don't understand what is going on.  I have tried restarting and reseting PRAM, no effect, and turning on and off my one extension (adblock), and I have tried incognito mode.

Comment: Out of curiosity...do you have the problem in Safari or Firefox?

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party audio drivers - Boom2, Soundflower, Loopback, Audio Hijack, Line6 etc ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am experiencing the same issue. Sound is fine everywhere, iTunes, Firefox, etc. but no sound in Chrome. Macpro Late 2013, Mojave 10.14.4, Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I have no sound in Chrome and videos on youtube won't play. It seems to happen after I connect to an external monitor while clamshelled.